# Strange behaviour of printf() and fprintf() calls in C with %s parameter

Tags: c, printf

When I am trying to print or write data in following way its automatically concatenating more than one string into one.

Following is the structure holding data:

```
typedef struct Data{
    int id;
    char fname[10];
    char lname[11];
    char address[27];
    char area[18];
    char city[21];
    char cityCode[3];
    char pinCode[5];
    char contact1[13];
    char contact2[13];
    char email[33];
}Data;

Data d;
```

When i try to print this in following manner

```
printf("\nData is as follow:\n");
printf("\nID:%d",d.id);
printf("\nfname:%s",d.fname);
printf("\nlname:%s",d.lname);
printf("\naddress:%s",d.address);
printf("\narea:%s",d.area);
printf("\nCity:%s",d.city);
printf("\nCityCode:%s",d.cityCode);
printf("\npinCode:%s",d.pinCode);
printf("\ncontact1:%s",d.contact1);
printf("\ncontact2:%s",d.contact2);
printf("\nemail:%s",d.email);
```

This is what i got

```
Data is as follow:

ID:1
fname:abc
lname:xyz
address: 6649 N test lane
area:Test City
City:testtest
CityCode:XYZ12345 123-456-6789789-456-6123
pinCode:12345 123-456-6789789-456-6123
contact1: 123-456-6789789-456-6123
contact2:789-456-6123
email:ttest@gmail.com
2
```

Same thing happened when I tried to write it on file using fprintf().

```
1,abc,xyz 6649 N test lane,Test City,testtest,XYZ12345 123-456-6789789-456-6123,12345 123-456-6789789-456-6123, 123-456-6789789-456-6123,789-456-6123,ttest@gmail.com
2
```

My main aim is to write the data on file separated by (,) and the data is

1,abc,xyz, 6649 N test lane,Test City,testtest,XYZ,12345, 123-456-6789,789-456-6123,ttest@gmail.com

Comment: You are most likely writing out of bounds.

Comment: citycode can hold 3 chars (2 + zero termination) but your input is `XYZ` which will require 4 chars (i.e. 3 + 1 for the zero termination). So citycode is too small for the input! My guess is that the code for reading the input doesn't check bounds correctly. **So don't just extend the array sizes! Fix the code for reading input so that it never writes out of bounds**

Comment: @4386427 your way did help me out thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm just guessing here, but if we take a look at the `cityCode` member, it is an array of three characters. To be a "string" of three characters, it needs space for *four* characters, to include the terminating `'\0'` character.

Make sure all arrays have space for, and *have*, the string terminator character.

Comment: Agree - I would also add that OP should fix the "input reading" code to ensure that out of bounds writes never will happen